# NSLocalizedString doesn't work

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, localization

I want to use NSLocalizedString in my app but it always failed. What i do is:

- Define 3 Localizations in Project Properties (See screenshot bellow)
- Create a new file: Resource Strings File
- Check in the app bundle if file.strings is there

Then I use NSLocalizedStrings as follow but it doesn't work!

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    NSString *v1 = NSLocalizedString(@"MyWindow", nil);

    //NSString *v1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] localizedStringForKey:(@"MyWindow") value:@"" table:nil];
    [label setStringValue:v1];
}
```

In my 3 .strings files I define the below key/value:
"MyWindow" = "Ma Fenetre";

Normally, my label should display "Ma Fenetre" and not "MyWindows"
You can download [an example project here and tell me where is the issue](http://dl.free.fr/mon.pl?i=115818&h=e5n8Q7dn).

Bellow the content of Resources folder in my app bundle :

```
DerivedData om$ find test/Build/Products/Debug/test.app/Contents/Resources/
test/Build/Products/Debug/test.app/Contents/Resources/
test/Build/Products/Debug/test.app/Contents/Resources//de.lproj
test/Build/Products/Debug/test.app/Contents/Resources//de.lproj/File.strings
test/Build/Products/Debug/test.app/Contents/Resources//en.lproj
test/Build/Products/Debug/test.app/Contents/Resources//en.lproj/File.strings
test/Build/Products/Debug/test.app/Contents/Resources//fr.lproj
test/Build/Products/Debug/test.app/Contents/Resources//fr.lproj/File.strings
test/Build/Products/Debug/test.app/Contents/Resources//MainMenu.nib
```

Thanks
Elfoiros

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`NSLocalizedString` uses `Localizable.strings` file by default. Change your `File.strings` name and try again.

Comment: Great answer! I had to change default infoplist.strings to Localizable.strings and it worked, thanks.

Comment: Sir, u saved my life

Answer (score 9):

For every time you make changes in .Strings file you need to clean your project and remove application from device and simulator. This is the only way to develop Localised application.
Have a happy coding.!

Comment: Programmers are people to help the world.

Answer (score 8):

As Adam stated, `NSLocalizedString` uses `Localizable.strings` for a lookup table. To specify a custom table, use:

`NSLocalizedStringFromTable(@"MyWindow", @"File");`

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBundle/localizedStringForKey%3avalue%3atable%3a)

Answer (score 3):

Need to take care over case sensitive file names: Localizable.strings not localizable.strings.  Simply rename in Finder, delete reference in Xcode project and add Localizable string back to the project.  Then make sure the appropriate Localization boxes are selected in the file inspector.  Don't know if there's a better slicker process.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue as described here but the solution was different. Somehow I managed to mangle how the Localization.strings file was being referenced in the project.

Removing the Localizable.strings file and readding it fixed the problem for me.